# how to DeserializeObject in viewmodel in xamarin form

Tags: forms, xamarin

I have model class like this from this i want to so threadUsers data in Listview from View Model.

```cs
public  class DealMessageThreadList
{
    public List<DealMessageThread> messages { get; set; }
    public List<threadUsers> threadUsers { get; set; }
}

public class DealMessageThread
{
    public string author { get; set; }
    public string authorId { get; set; }
    public DateTime createdDate { get; set; }
    public string plainContent { get; set; }
    public string threadId { get; set; }
}

public partial class threadUsers
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string userid_10 { get; set; }
}

public partial class threadUsers
{
    public static ObservableCollection<threadUsers> FromJson(string json) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<threadUsers>>(json);
}
```

and now i want to deserialize threadusers in view model, following is method in ViewModel. and now i want to deserialize threadusers in view model, following is method in ViewModel.

```cs
public async Task FetchThreadUserData()
{
    using (HttpClient hc = new HttpClient())
    {
        try
        {
            IsBusy = true;
            var jsonString = await hc.GetStringAsync(url);
            var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DealMessageThreadList>(jsonString);
            //IEnumerable<threadUsers> lstThreadUsers;
            lstThreadUsers = obj.threadUsers.Select(t => new threadUsers()
            {
                userid_10 = t.userid_10,
                name = t.name
            });
            //here list is itemsourse of listview 
            list = lstThreadUsers;
        }
        finally
        {
            IsBusy = false;
        }
    }
}
```

How to get data and populate to listview? I want to populate threadUsers data in Listview. i created `IEnumerable<threadUsers> lstThreadUsers;` but it not populating in list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering this based on a couple of assumptions:

- your variable `list` is a public property of type `ObservableCollection<threadUsers>`
- `list` is already instantiated
- you have bound `list` to a ListView looking something like: `<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding list}">`

With those two assumptions you should simply be able to change your code as follows.

After you deserialize your object, instead of making a new `IEnumerable<treadUsers>` and copying `threadUsers` objects into it, copy them into your `ObservableCollection` instead:

```cs
foreach(var user in obj.threadUsers)
    list.Add(user);
```

Since `list` is an `ObservableCollection` it will automatically notify a `ListView` it is bound to, that it has updated.